# How to resolve this error "Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest> into a @BeforeTest annotated setUp" this error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

Getting the below error 
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setUp
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Can inject only one of  into a @BeforeTest annotated setUp.
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection

```
public static WebDriver driver;
ReadConfig rcg=new ReadConfig();
protected String firstname=rcg.getFirstName();
protected String secondName=rcg.getSecondName();
protected String email=rcg.getEmail();
protected String company_name=rcg.getCompany();
protected String phone_number=rcg.getPhone();
protected String url=rcg.getUrl();
protected String br=rcg.getbrowser();
@BeforeTest
public void setUp(String br)
    {
    this.br=br;
    if(br.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
    {

  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",System.getProperty
    (("user.dir")+"\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe"));
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get(url);
    }
    else if(br.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
    {
        System.setProperty
 ("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(url);
    }

}
@AfterTest
public void teardown()
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For the @BeforeTest method you are passing arguments. So it is expecting parameter from your xml. Since it is not annotated with @Parameters({Parameter Name}) it was throwing the error. So annotate your method like below.

```
@BeforeTest
@Parameters({"BrowserName"})
void setUp(String br)
```

From your xml, pass the parameter value

```
<test>
<parameter name="BrowserName" value="Chrome"></parameter>
-----
</test>
```

And also it is duplicate question of below which is aleady been answered.

[How to resolve this error "Can inject only one of <ITestContext, XmlTest> into a @BeforeTest annotated setUp" this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60306534/how-to-resolve-this-error-can-inject-only-one-of-itestcontext-xmltest-into-a)